# RecyclerView divider with a character

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to display a list of items and separate them using a "<" character as the divider to convey information about relationships between those items. Also, I should be able to hide the divider after the last item in the list. I am new to Android dev, so I am using the RecyclerView by and large because it is presumed to be the native/right way of showing lists of things in Android. The resulting UI should look like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoJmj.jpg

I've researched this and found that there is a built-in ItemDecoration functionality for a RecyclerView. However, I was only able to find how to draw a line:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL));
```

From what I can see, you have to use a drawable for this one and that it is still not very convenient to hide the last divider.

The other option that I found is to create a heterogeneous layout inside the RecyclerView's Adapter: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView, So, put the divider as a second viewType layout and inflate it after the item layout. But that seems like an overkill and also makes the Adapter less reusable. Similar to that, there is an option to create a layout for the RecyclerView with both (item and divider) views in it and inflate them in the RecyclerView's Adapter. However, it also does not seem like an intended way of doing this.

I am pretty sure this functionality is possible, but I have doubts if any of the ways I listed is the right one to go with. Any suggestions?

Comment: how many items are there in your list?

Comment: You can will have separate layout for recycler view item in that you can keep the arrow mark at left centre, by recycler view adapter only you will be setting the list. In that each item property add boolean property (based on this you can show/hide). At any time you can change the property of particular item and update list.

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply achieved in your layouts and the model you pass to your ViewHolder in order to bind it.
To be more clear, your model could have a flag, specifying if the divider should be shown or not, then while binding the view accordingly, simply show/hide that "<" thing or any other kind of a divider/view. So inside your item layout [or your view which can be created programmatically], you can add for example a `TextView` as your divider and set its visibility to `GONE` or `VISIBLE`.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is creating your own ItemDecoration implementation. You just have to override two methods.

With `getItemOffsets()` you add offset between the items, it is similar to adding padding or margin.

Now that you have "free" space between the RecyclerView items, by overriding the `onDraw()` method you can easily draw the "<" character using the provided `Canvas` object `drawText()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to consider "<" in your item layout through TextView. 
If you just want to hide it on last item then you can check like:

```
if(position==list.Size()-1){
   divider.setVisibility(View.Gone)
}else{
   divider.setVisibility(View.Visible)
}
```

If you have some other logic to hide/show then change it accordingly.

In this way you can also change the character if relationship changes or hide/show it in any item of list. Not just in the last item.